# How can I handle window messages from a separate thread know when it is handled?

Tags: windows

The separate thread is a game app over which I have no control other than sending keys (keydown and keyup messages).  I can do that when I attach my threat to the game.

My question is, how can I determine when the game has processed a key (down,  up)?

I have tried using peekmessage with NOREMOVE but that always returns 0 (there is never a key waiting).

I am trying to get the fastest response in playing the game.

I currently am using a heuristic of about 130 ms after sending a keydown before I send a keyup.  That works most of the time but is not 100% reliable.  I need a reliable means of sending keys.

What are my options?
-Doug

Comment: There's no generic solution.  Only the game itself knows when it has processed a key.  You'll have to experiment, or reverse engineer the game to see what it is doing.  There might not be any good solution.

Comment: Thank you.  I am coming to the same conclusion.